# Map firebase response to class

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I have the following class:

```
import { Hobbies } from './hobbies';

export class Results {

constructor(
    $key: string,
    first_name: string,
    gender: string,
    intent: string,
    seeking: string,
    training: string,
    latitude: string,
    longitude: string,
    location_desc: string,
    state: string,
    hobbies: Hobbies[],
    cloud_Id: string) {

}

static fromJsonList(array): Results[] {
    return array.map(json => Results.fromJson(json))
}

static fromJson({ $key, cloud_Id, first_name, gender, hobbies, intent, latitude, location_desc, longitude, seeking, state, training }): Results {

    debugger;
    return new Results(
        $key,
        first_name,
        gender,
        intent,
        seeking,
        training,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        location_desc,
        state,
        hobbies,
        cloud_Id);
}


}
```

I make a call to `Firebase` and retrieve a list of users who state matches the location I pass in as shown here:

```
getSearchResults(location: string): Observable<Results[]> {

        return this.af.database.list('/user/', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'state',
                equalTo: location
            }
        }).map(Results.fromJsonList);
}
```

I then `.map` the response to `(Results.fromJsonList);`

Inside the `static` method `fromJson`, when I hit the `debugger` breakpoint and check the values being passed, they're all correct.

However when I log the results within my component:

```
getSearchResultsComponent(gender: string, seeking: string, intent: string, location: string, hobbies?: string) {

  this.searchSubscription = this.searchService.getSearchResults(location).subscribe(results => {
   console.log(results);
  });

}
```

I see the following:

[image]

Whereas I should be seeing the entries for two users, i.e first_name, gender, location etc.

Can someone explain to why this mapping isn't working the way I envisioned it working?

Comment: @PankajParkar `body.json is not a function` is the error i get when I try your recommendation.  I will point out though when I step into this function I can see the the `new Results()` being populated with the values I pass in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all `Results` class members `public` so that they can be reachable via object instance. Currently you just had parameters passed to `Results` `constructor`, they aren't got assigned to any class member.

```
export class Results {

    constructor(
        public $key: string,
        public first_name: string,
        public gender: string,
        public intent: string,
        public seeking: string,
        public training: string,
        public latitude: string,
        public longitude: string,
        public location_desc: string,
        public state: string,
        public hobbies: Hobbies[],
        public cloud_Id: string
    )
    //other code
}
```

Comment: @CodeRatchet glad to help you, Thanks :)